# is synchronous in separate thread the same as asynchronous

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsoperation, synchronous

Recently, i am learning concurrency in swift. According to apple's document in `NSOperation class reference` :

> When you add an operation to an operation queue, the queue ignores the value of the asynchronous property and always calls the start method from a separate thread. Therefore, if you always run operations by adding them to an operation queue, there is no reason to make them asynchronous.

does it mean synchronous in a separate thread is the same as asynchronous? and when i do the test with the following code, the operation indeed doesn't block the current main thread.

```
let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
let operation = NSBlockOperation(){
    //do some task here
}
operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
```

so if it is true, then why should we create concurrency subclass of NSOperation?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, `NSOperation`. Such a bizarre history you have.

`NSOperation` is relatively old (in iOS terms; fairly modern in ObjC terms). It was added in OS X 10.5. Before OS X 10.6/iOS 4, there were no `NSBlockOperation` objects. There were no blocks at all. So the only way to make an operation was to subclass or use `NSInvocationOperation`. Both approaches are cumbersome, but were still easier and more powerful than the older approach of using `NSThread` directly.

(This was right at the time when multi-core became a thing. 10.5 was famous for adding Core Animation which was I believe the first major preemptive multitasking framework in Cocoa. Before 10.5, most things were done with the runloop and cooperative multitasking, which is actually very efficient and effective for single-core systems. But it doesn't scale well to multi-core systems. Tools like `NSOperation` were provided to help us write better multi-core code, but GCD was *so* much more powerful that it completely dominated how multitasking code is written in Cocoa.)

When you subclass `NSOperation`, you needed to tell the system whether your operation is asynchronous. This isn't a request to run you asynchronously. This is a promise that your `start` method will not block. It's up to your `start` method to make sure the operation really is asynchronous.

This is only necessary in the case that your `NSOperation` is being started manually, and even then it was often not needed. If you put it onto an `NSOperationQueue` (and you really should always do that), this property is irrelevant. I remember it creating a lot of confusion at the time.

It's become even more irrelevant since the introduction of blocks. It is almost always much easier to use an `NSBlockOperation` (or `dispatch_async`) than to subclass `NSOperation`, which was always a bit tricky to get quite right.

Just in case you haven't already read it, if you want to study Cocoa concurrency, you definitely want to start with the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1).

Comment: Really thanks.If i understand correctly, you mean synchronous in a separate thread indeed is the same as asynchronous. And actually, there is no need to change the asynchronous property when using `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Correct on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous is always defined relative to the thread that makes a request.  So a request is asynchronous relative to thread A if thread A makes a request that runs in thread B such that thread A is able to do other work while thread B is running the request.

If thread B in turn farms out the request to thread C such that thread B is able to do other work while thread C is running the request then that second request is an asynchronous relative to thread B.

It doesn't make sense to just keep farming out the same element of work asynchronously over and over again, of course.  But assume the work delegated by thread A to thread B described above can be split up into multiple smaller elements of work.  It would be reasonable for thread B to invoke those smaller elements of work asynchronously on threads C, D, etc.  This might happen if B provides a service to A such that A doesn't want/need to know the details of how the work gets done; it just wants the work done asynchronously.  B knows the details and can decide if/how to accomplish the work via smaller parallel units.